# Creating a PDF file in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf-generation

I'm  trying to build an Android app that generates a simple PDF documents.

I wrote this function:

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    fun createDocument(text: String) {
        val pdf = PdfDocument()
        val page = pdf.startPage(PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(
            100, 100, 1).create())
        val canvas = page.canvas
        val paint = Paint()

        try {
            canvas.drawText(text,20F,30F,paint)
            pdf.finishPage(page)

            val fileName = "doc${System.currentTimeMillis()}.pdf"
            val file = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), fileName)

            pdf.writeTo(file.outputStream())
            pdf.close()

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$fileName has been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error: ${e.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

When I'm running this code I see the toast message but no file is created, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "but no file is created" -- where and how are you looking for it?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm looking at the system 'Documents' directory.
I'm using the Android Studio emulator.

Comment: Well you saved to a different storage location. Better look in getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: "I'm looking at the system 'Documents' directory" -- that is not where you are writing the file. Where you are writing it amounts to `Android/data/.../files/`, where `...` is your application ID. While that is a bit awkward, it is in many ways your best option if you want a file that users can access directly *and* that you have direct filesystem access to as well.

Comment: @CommonsWare How can I get to this location in the emulator?

Comment: @ygeyzel: `Android` should be a peer of `Documents`, so however you were looking at `Documents` may work. Or, use Android Studio's Device File Explorer to examine [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: Ok, I've found it

Answer (score 0):

As [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) and [blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps) noted, the document is actually created and saved but in a different location than the one I've looked at.

The document location is *<device-sd>*/Android/data/*<app.id>*/files/Documents/*<document-name>*